# Fill gridview using javascript on selected tree node value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

my requirement is to get the result in gridview based on the treeview node selection using javascript i.e. client scripting. Currently the same can be achieved using server side scripting, but i want to do this without postback and without using selectednodeindexchanged event. Pls. help me to solve this problem.

Comment: have you got your answer

Comment: i think yes... its possible with gird view just google it and if any queries reply back

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite involved but goes something like this:

- Use the `Page.GetCallbackEventReference` method to make an `XmlHttpReques`t back to the server and retrieve a json object that will be used to populated the grid.
- See the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace for pointers on how to convert your objects to JSON.
- Create a JavaScript closure to encapsulate your grid update logic. Something like:

```
var vm = {
  someField: 'test',

  init: function() {

  },

  update: function(data) {
     var grid = document.getElementById('yourGrid');
     // loop through the data and set the innerHTML on the cells to whatever your data is.
  }
}

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.init();
}, 100);

// In the aspx/ascx
//when the callback completes convert the json to an object like this
var d = eval('(' + data + ')');
//call update on your object
vm.update(data)
```